Need Field Extraction Syntax in Azure Logic App
I am using the Document Intelligence contract model and an Azure Logic app for field extraction. For the 'Title' field, I am using the following syntax: items('For_each')?['fields']?['Title']?['content'], and I am getting the output.
However, when I try to extract the 'Parties' field using items('For_each')?['fields']?['Parties']?['content'], it is not working and does not return any value.
Can you provide me with the correct syntax to extract the content of the 'Parties' array field?
items('For_each')?['fields']?['Parties']?['value']

Show us the json.

Parties is an array.
To get the content for the first party item in the array, you can use the following syntax:
items('For_each')?['fields']?['Parties']?[0]?['content']

or - depending on the data structure -
items('For_each')?['fields']?['Parties']?[0]?['valueObject']?['Address']?['content']

(Having the JSON included in the question will help you receive more accurate answers)
If you need to get the content of each party, you can do it using the For each loop over the Parties array just as you did it over the documents array.

It will be
items('For_each')?['fields']?['Parties']?['valueArray']
to be added in For Each loop
then
items('For_each_2')?['valueObject']?['Address']?['content']
